# mysql: WHERE column ENDS ON value

Tags: mysql

I tried this query:

```
var sqlString1 = "SELECT status \
FROM 10561_12865_tblInvites \
WHERE invitedPersonIdentifier  = '" + value +"' AND \
tblEventID  = '" + eventID +"'";
```

It is a working query but it only compars exact matches.
For invitedPersonIdentifier however I want to just check for a match in the last 5 digits of whatever the column consists of.

So say the column is asd12345
and the value I am querying on is "12345", I still want to find a match here.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: Don't concate queries and variables, especially if they are from user input, to avoid SQL injections. Use parameterized queries instead

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: an example of the concate thing :) I am no longer stuck syntactly

Comment: @innom it's language dependant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `LIKE` with `%` sign:

```
SELECT status FROM 10561_12865_tblInvites WHERE invitedPersonIdentifier LIKE '%12345';
```

> % is used to match any number of characters, even zero characters.

More details here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: The linked doc is for SQLite

Comment: Yes, sorry. Changed with more generic explanation for SQL.

Comment: Great! Thank you, got it working immediately!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use LIKE keyword. For instance:

```
Select status
fom invites
where identifier like '%12345%';
```

more information:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: this would also work if the string is a substring. i want to make it end specific.